# Word for people living in poverty

Tags: single-word-requests

Can anyone help me identify a proper word for a person or persons living in poverty?

I'm looking for a noun that satisfies the description, which isn't just an adjective turned noun (ex. the poor).

Comment: *Poor person* seems apt. *Disadvantaged* might be more PC.

Comment: Are you looking for an adjective that describes their living conditions or a noun to call this person?

Comment: Noun to call this person, @Mari-LouA.

Comment: *A pauper* is one of *the poor*.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. Please edit your post, include this piece of information and perhaps an explanation  as to why the expression [the poor](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/the+poor) does not satisfy you.

Comment: How about someone in a `state of penury`? Penury: extreme poverty; destitution

Comment: [*povvy*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=povvy)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Thanks for the suggestion, and sorry for not being as specific earlier. Thanks.

Comment: What is your problem with adjectives used as nouns, by the way? Apart from _pauper_, all the upvoted suggestions are adjectives

Comment: Just curiousity, since, as you've pointed out, the most common ones used are adjectives turned nouns.

Answer (score 5):

Indigent is a formal word to name poor people.

[**Indigent**](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/indigent)(adj.)

> needy; poor; impoverished.

**The indigent**(n.) [plural; used with a plural verb]

> people who are indigent.
>   For example, *a desire to do something for the indigent*.

You also have [***the badly off***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/badly-off).

Comment: You should include the name of the source, e.g. The Free Dictionary, Collins Dictionary, AHD... adding a link would be perfect.

Comment: Blimey! All right... forthwith re-editing it!

Answer (score 4):

**[Destitute](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/destitute)**

> extremely poor and lacking the means to provide for oneself.

**[Impecunious](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/impecunious)**

> without money; penniless

[**Penurious**](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20penurious)

> extremely poor; poverty-stricken.

Along with these single-word synonyms, idioms like the ones I've mentioned below may also help.

[**On the breadline**](http://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idiom-categories/money/money1.html)

People who live on the breadline have a very low income or barely enough money to survive.

[**Live from hand to mouth**](http://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idiom-categories/money/money3_ill-gotten-loan.html)

If you live from hand to mouth, you don't have any money to save because whatever you earn is spent on food and other essentials.
Most families in that area live from  hand to mouth.

[**Make ends meet**](http://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idiom-categories/money/money4_million-more.html)

If you find it difficult to pay for your everyday needs because you have very little money, it is hard for you to make ends meet.

Answer (score 3):

*[Needy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/needy?q=needy%3A)* is a common expression:

> adjective (needier, neediest)
>
> 1 (Of a person) lacking the necessities of life; very poor:
>   *needy and elderly people*

The adjective is often used substantively for a class of poor people: *We have targeted assistance to the needy.*

Comment: A person could say "My boyfriend/girlfriend is needy" even though that friend is wealthy. A person could be living in poverty, yet all their basic needs are met.

Comment: Yes @hatchet, and a person could say that [*sanction*](http://mentalfloss.com/article/49834/14-words-are-their-own-opposites) means to ***offer official approval***--but it also means nearly the opposite: ***impose a penalty***. Welcome to the rich semantics of the English language :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Have-not](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/have-not?q=have+not)s:

> A person, nation, etc., that has little or nothing of something,
>   especially money or material possessions; a poor or disadvantaged
>   person, nation, etc. Frequently in **plural** Contrasted with have, have-got.

Economically [disadvantaged](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disadvantaged) people:

> (Of a person or area) in unfavourable circumstances, especially with
>   regard to financial or social opportunities.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]