# Is there a euphemistic word for "of or relating to the bottom socioeconomic class"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Can someone provide an adjective that means "a poor man's" but doesn't possess any negative connotation?

For instance:

> Crack is the (poor man's) cocaine.

Comment: Impecunious, indigent, underpriviledged.

Comment: Related question, [Word for people living in poverty](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257458/word-for-people-living-in-poverty).

Comment: In my opinion, every answer so far has a more negative connotation than "poor".  Just use poor, if that is what you mean.

Comment: What makes you think that "*poor*" generally has a negative connotation? Depends on who is doing the thinking about it, and in what context.

Comment: One thing for sure is crack is not the poor man's cocaine.

Comment: Do you need to refer to people at all? Why not *crack is a cheap alternative to cocaine*.

Comment: @WSJ I'm not actually writing about crack, it was just an illustrative example.

Comment: @Rathony You've obviously never been to DC.

Comment: @Rathony Was that the subtext? Must've missed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous phrases for this in the field of social policy. I believe the current one is *[disadvantaged](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disadvantaged)*:-

> lacking in the basic resources or conditions (as standard housing,
>   medical and educational facilities, and civil rights) believed to be
>   necessary for an equal position in society [Merriam-Webster]

but they change very quickly and I don't pretend to keep up. So you sentence might read *crack is the cocaine of the disadvantaged*.

Answer (score 1):

How about [disenfranchised](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disenfranchised)?

Apart from its more technical denotation, it can also be used to describe a voiceless person within society; someone who for various reasons does not have a say in society at large.

I think it safe to say that poverty can be an implied companion of disenfranchisement, but not necessarily. Sometimes a person who is relatively well off can be discriminated against for reasons having nothing to do with their economic standing in society.

Still, *disenfranchised* can pass muster as a euphemism, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

*underprivileged, on the breadline, disadvantaged, necessitous*.. these words are not completely euphemistic but are somewhat lesser in degree than *poor*.

Comment: Hi, Quality Talk. We discourage users to post an answer without any research/reference/link that can support it and **disadvantaged** has been posted by Brian Hooper. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

***[Bottom of the pyramid or BOP](http://lexicon.ft.com/Term?term=bottom-of-the-pyramid-(BOP))***  is a definition used in socio-economic contexts:

> - The Bottom of the Pyramid (BOP) is a socio-economic concept that allows us to group that vast segment  - in excess of about four billion  - of the world’s poorest citizens constituting an invisible and unserved market blocked by challenging barriers that prevent them from realising their human potential for their own benefit, those of their families, and that of society's at large.
> - Technically, a member of the BOP is part of the largest but poorest groups of the world's population, who live with less than $2.50 a day and are excluded from the modernity of our globalised civilised societies, including consumption and choice as well as access to organised financial services.
> - Some estimates based on the broadest segment of the BOP put its demand as consumers at about $5 trillion in Purchasing Power Parity terms, making it a desirable objective for creative and leading visionary businesses throughout the world. One of the undeniable successes in this process is the explosion of the Microfinance industry witnessed in many parts of the world.

(lexicon.ft.com)
[image]

Comment: BOP does not seem "euphemistic" to me.  It's more specifically factual in an economics context.

Comment: @KristinaLopez - well, it does sound euphemistic to me. No longer "the poorest" but just  BOP members.

Comment: Who'd know what "BOP members" mean, though, outside the realm of economists?